# In C, my output of a function is always 0.000000. Is it because the two inputs are int?

Tags: c, function, int, output

I know you're usually not meant to put out all of your code but this is short and would help with the problem. Can anyone please explain why the output is 0 and how I can change the code to output what should be the volume of a cone.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float ConeVolume(int height, int radius);

float ConeVolume(int height, int radius)
{
    float pi;
    pi = 3.14159;
    float third;
    third = (1/3);
    float vol;
    vol = third * pi * radius * radius * height;
    return vol;
}


int main()
{
float x = ConeVolume(12,10);
printf("%.4f \n", x);
}
```

edit: thank you to all who answered so quickly. Great community here.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then use the debugger (`gdb`) by single stepping your program. You would have found your bug quickly (faster than asking here).

Comment: there are uncountable duplicates of this on SO

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
1/3
```

is an integer division and always results in `0`.

To have this evaluate to a floating point variable you might do

```
1./3
```

or

```
1/3.
```

or

```
1./3.
```

or even more explicit

```
(float)1/(float)3
```

for example.

Comment: I was about to add (not quite serious) that it's not the `./` operator in action there :) But then you showed the other variations and I think it became clear that you are dividing floats :)

Comment: Ah yes, missed the `./`-operator ... dxxm, failed again ;-) @JohannesSchaub-litb

Comment: It is not a `./` operator, it is a `/` operator applied to `1.` and `3`

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
#include <stdio.h>

float ConeVolume(int height, int radius)
{
    float pi, vol;
    pi = 3.14159;
    vol =  (pi * radius * radius * height) / 3;
    return vol;
}


void main()
{
    float x = ConeVolume(12,10);
    printf("%.4f \n", x);
    system("pause");
}
```