# How to print fraction in C

Tags: c, fractions

I had a problem trying to print a fraction in C. How I can print the fraction as the number I defined below. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%.4f\n", 153/400);
    return 0;
}
```

Any help will appreciated.

Comment: Write 400.0 because it is integer division now which can only have integer result. This way it will be floating point division.

Comment: @Eraklon Turn that into an answer please.

Comment: [In C, my output of a function is always 0.000000. Is it because the two inputs are int?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32932941/995714), [Why does division result in zero instead of a decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8906722/995714), [calculation in C program always results in 0 whenever using division](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7720078/995714)

Answer (score 3):

You doing integer division now which will only result in integer. You have to perform floating point division. You can easily achieve this by writing `400.0` instead of `400` or casting one of the operand (or both if you will) to `float` like `153/(float)400`.

**Edit:** As @Erwan Daniel rightly noted you have to use `400.0f` to have a `float` literal, since on default it will be double.

Comment: 400.0 will make a double. As C keep the most precise type, all the calculation will be made in double. The right way to write it is 400.0f of 400.f, the point is mandatory.

Comment: @ErwanDaniel You are perfectly right. Corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: `float` in vanadic args  is prompted to `double` (since c99/c+11). Also `int` to `float` conversion may trigger lose precision warning because it is actually may lose precision. No sense to make `float` here.

Comment: @ErwanDaniel: Why use `float` rather than `double`? The question does not request it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil No one said to use a float or double. It's just to show that 400.0 makes double and not a float, to avoid any confusion. But AskoldIlvento is explaning just before you why to use double rather than float.